# Laravel Vue Inertia dynamic pagination bugging with mount

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using a dynamic query in Laravel Inertia, my pagination is bugging because every time i try to change the pagination the mount() method of vue runs.

```
 data() {
        return {
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                search: this.filters.search,
                order: "asc",
                column: "code",
                size: 5,
            }),
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$inertia.get(this.route("groups.index"), pickBy(this.form), {
            preserveState: true,
        });
    },
    watch: {
        form: {
            deep: true,
            handler: throttle(function () {
                this.$inertia.get(
                    this.route("groups.index"),
                    pickBy(this.form),
                    { preserveState: true }
                );
            }, 150),
        },
    },
```

I need the mount() only on the first time or the component get rendered, but I dont want the mount() function to run everytime I use or change my pagination, is there any work around for this?

```
'groups' => Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->when($request->search, function($query, $term){
                $query->where('code', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%')
                      ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE' , '%' . $term. '%');
            })->when($request->column, function($query, $term) use ($request){
                $query->orderBy($term, $request->order);
            })->paginate($request->size)->withQueryString(),
```

This is my query.

Comment: I think the key has been changed after pagination for pagination component that why it re-render and mount function call again and again

Comment: Th Me problem is the mount function runs everytime I change the pagination thus reseting the table.

Comment: then you need to find the way why it is happing. the possible reason is changing the key in list rendering.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why state isn't being preserved in your case, i would need to test it.

I handle it slightly differently (example using the composition api)

I don't do a request on mounted, that seems kind of redundant and maybe what's causing your issue, you shouldn't need to filter on mounted as when you are initially mounted it should be your initial request and the user didn't change anything in the fiters yet

```js
// you can also get the current filters from route().params
// current filters coming from the server
const props = defineProps({
    filters: Object,
})

const form = reactive({
    search: props.filters.search,
    order: props.filters.order,
    column: props.filters.column,
    size: props.filters.size,
})

const filter = throttle(function() {
    Inertia.get(route(route().current()), pickBy(form), {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
    })
}, 150)

watch(form, filter)
```